# Getting this error: "Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting this error, "Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render", for both *isActive* and *pointBreakdown* but I'm not sure why.
Here is my code:

```
import Vue from '../main/vue'

const loadCalculator = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('.calculator')) {
        new Vue({
            el: '.calculator',
            data: {
                    isActive: false,
                  },
            methods: {
                 pointBreakdown() {
                     this.isActive = !this.isActive
                 }
            }
        })
    }
}

export default loadCalculator
```

Here is my twig file:

```
<div class="flex-col items-center">
  <button class="fw-bold mt-sm text-sm flex items-center point-breakdown-toggler c-blue- 
  400 hover:c-blue-900" @click="pointBreakdown()">
    <span class="mr-sm">View point breakdown</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
It was how the class was being called, had to put the class on the parent div. Thanks all

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re conditionally instantiating the Vue app? That’s probably where the error is coming from.

Comment: Where is `.calculator` in the template?

Comment: please notice that your function doesn't return the new due instance, rather than just creating it and basically doing nothing with it

Answer (score 0):

I think your data-Property needs to be a function which returns an object.

```
data() {
    return {
        isActive: false
    }
}
```